# Show on Main form the value of a Text box on sub form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a sub form (continuous form) which shows the sum of Fee in a Text Box in the subform footer:

```
Text5 data =Sum(Fee).
```

This works correctly. What I can't do is show that value in another Text Box on the main form. I have tried

```
TFees = Forms!frmInvoice![frmInvoiceDetails].Form.Text5
```

This shows nothing (Null?) on the main from. No errors. My data for the subform is:

```
SELECT 
    tblInvoiceDetails.InvoiceLookup, 
    tblInvoiceDetails.DiscLookup, 
    [ApplicantSurname] & ', ' & [ApplicantForenames] AS AppName, 
    [DBSFee]+[MyFee] AS Fee, 
    tblDisclosure.Client, 
    tblDisclosure.Payer 
FROM 
    tblInvoiceDetails 
INNER JOIN 
    tblDisclosure 
    ON tblInvoiceDetails.DiscLookup = tblDisclosure.ID 
WHERE 
    (((tblDisclosure.Payer)='Client')) 
ORDER BY 
    [ApplicantSurname] & ', ' & [ApplicantForenames];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=Forms!frmInvoice!NameOfYourSubformControl.Form!Text5
```

Replace "NameOfYourSubformControl" with that name, not the name of the form.

Comment: Its name is frmInvoiceDetails. TFees = Forms!frmInvoice!frmInvoiceDetails.Form!Text5 gives the result 0.00, no matter what value appears on the subform. TFees = Sum(Forms!frmInvoice!frmInvoiceDetails.Form!Fee) gives the error message 'sub or function not defined'.

Comment: The expressions are for `ControlSource`, not for use in code.

Comment: = Forms!frmInvoice!frmInvoiceDetails.Form!Text5 worked. Many thanks. That's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
TFees.value = Forms("frmInvoiceDetails").Text5.value
```

Comment: What kind of error? Another option is to add ".value" to both text box names to your code.

Comment: #Error is what shows in TFees text Box - when I add 'value' to both text box names.

Comment: The name of Text Box on the main form is Text14. ControlSource =TFees(). Public Function TFees() As Variant

TFees.Value = Forms("frmInvoiceDetails").Text5.Value

End Function